# SQLite3 using a variable when creating a table?

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I am hoping to pass a table name as a variable when I am creating a table with Ruby and in SQLite3.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$db.execute %q{
  CREATE TABLE @tableName (
  id integer primary key,
  term varchar(100),
  meaning varchar(100))
}
```

$db is defined as

```
$db = SQLite3::Database.new("test.db")
$db.results_as_hash = true
```

@tableName is user input. I can see that it doesn't like the @tableName, but I don't know how to work around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use normal string interpolation:

```
$db.execute %Q{
  CREATE TABLE #{@tableName} (
  id integer primary key,
  term varchar(100),
  meaning varchar(100))
}
```

Note that I switched your `%q{}` quoting to `%Q{}` to get the interpolation to work.

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried using #{@tableName} but kept receiving errors, which caused me to doubt the #{@tableName} approach and prompted me to post. Thanks for the %Q{} tip!

Comment: @Naz: `%q{}` acts like single quotes, `%Q{}` acts like double quotes.

Comment: Thanks so much for both comments - it definitely makes a lot more sense now!

Answer (score 3):

%q is a single quote alternative, interpolation does not work inside single quoted strings.
Also in ruby interpolation is done with #{}, like in `"Welcome #{name}"`.
I would try:

```
$db.execute <<-SQL
  CREATE TABLE #{@tableName} (
    id integer primary key,
    term varchar(100),
    meaning varchar(100)
  )
SQL
```

Comment: thanks! I should have read up more on the .execute as I didn't realize you could use that format with it.